# SVN Merge new line from trunk to branch conflict

Tags: svn, svn-merge

Whilst merging revisions from the trunk to a branch I am looking to achieve the following:

Revision 1 (This is also the branch version):

```
First Line
```

Revision 2:

```
First Line
Second Line
```

Revision 3:

```
First Line
Second Line
Third Line
```

By executing the following command on the branch:

```
svn merge -c 3 [trunkurl]
```

I am expecting to get the following result

```
First Line
Third Line
```

But instead I am getting a tree conflict.
This technique seems to work fine for adding new lines in the middle of files, just not to the end of a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had *bad and wrong* expectation, but Subversion (without tree conflict, only with **file conflict** /tree conflict is impossible here/) raised correct error

When Subversion merge, it tries to /to some degree, real merge-algorithm is a lot more complex/ **apply diffs** (unified, with default context = 3, AFAIR) from source tree for affected revisions to target. If you'll try to see at diff of your HEAD, you'll see

```
Index: file.txt
===================================================================
--- file.txt    (revision 4)
+++ file.txt    (revision 5)
@@ -1,2 +1,3 @@
 First Line
 Second Line
+Third Line
```

but this context doesn't exist in branch, thus - even ordinary `patch` with *default settings* will reject this diff